# TestCase class junit.extensions.ExceptionTestCase is missing a public constructor with no parameters or a single String parameter

Tags: android

Context:Windows 7 OS, Latest Android ADT IDE, robotium jar files, Android

Query: I created a testrobotium class which on execution as android junit, should trigger the AUT i.e. the android application. On execution of the testrobotium class as android junit I get the following error in the logcat:

```
01-24 12:17:44.708: I/TestGrouping(2235): TestCase class junit.extensions.ExceptionTestCase is missing a public constructor with no parameters or a single String parameter - skipping
01-24 12:17:44.790: I/TestRunner(2235): started: null(com.sap.esm.retail.test.InitialTest)
```

The code for the InitialTest class including the constructor goes like this:

```
package com.sap.esm.retail.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import com.sap.esm.retail.MobileRetailingActivity;
import com.sap.esm.retail.OrderSumaryActivity;
import com.sap.esm.retail.ProductDetailsActivity;
import com.sap.esm.retail.ShippingDetailsActivity;

import com.sap.esm.retail.R;

public class InitialTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MobileRetailingActivity> {

    public Solo solo;
    private TextView cartNo;
    private ImageView Img;
    private String actualTot;


    public InitialTest(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(MobileRetailingActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

...........
```

Thus, there is some issue with the constructor i think.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide package of app in your constructor, look here:
http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started
It should look like this:

```
public InitialTest() {
     super("com.sap.esm.retail", MobileRetailingActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: I finally found out the issue. I was doing a maven build. Maven was doing the build fine but the dependency jar files were not getting provided when the android junit test was run. I removed the maven dependencies and used lib folders to contain the jar files. It worked fine.